# Laravel - Math computations in blades

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to add two integers from the database inside a blade?

To give a scenario, I have a controller that compacts a collection of `orders` table.

```
$solditems =  DB::table('orders')
            ->where('status', 'served')
            ->orderBy('id')
            ->get();

        return view('salesreports.sellingitems.index', compact('solditems'));
```

And I used those like this in my blade.

```
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Sales</th>
                    </tr>
                <thead>
                </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @forelse($solditems as $solditem) 
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$solditem->id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$solditem->item}}</td>
                                <td>{{$solditem->subtotal}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @empty
                        @endforelse
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Now, what I want to do is to combine an item that has same item names or `$solditem->item` while adding up there subtotals.

For example;

```
ID #1 Apple = 50
ID #2 Apple = 80
```

Will become this;

```
ID #1 Apple = 130
```

I tried using groupBy on query builder so an item with same name will only show once, but I'm having problems designing an algorithm adding up the subtotal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one,
This gives you sum of cost with same item name for all items.

```
$solditems =  DB::table('orders')
              ->where('status', 'served')
              ->select('orders.*',DB::raw('SUM() as total'))
              ->groupBy('orders.item')
              ->orderBy('id')
              ->get();
```

Comment: Hello. I tried your suggestion but I'm having this error code; `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064` it's linked with that `select` part.

Comment: Oh! I was pretty dumb. I didn't add subtotal in `SUM()` parameters. So what I did was changed it to `SUM(subtotal) as subtotal` and it worked like magic. Thank you! :)

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Any way congrats

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of Laravel's collection methods. You can use the [GroupBy method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby) to create grouped subarrays by product name and foreach of those group using the [Sum method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sum) return the sum of the total column.